# How to quickly delete folder (or erase disc completely)

Tags: bitlocker, eraser

is there a way how to quickly delete folder (containing cca 500 000 files / size 0,5 TB)?
I do this quite often and it takes about 15 minutes (Windows 10, USB 3.0, HDD encrypted with BitLocker).

No wiping (secure overwrite) is necessary.

Background: I have external HDD for backup and I have to make space to save data.
Formatting HDD might be an option, BUT I use BitLocker and after formatting I have to

1. switch BitLocker on and
2. print and save recovery key on safe place (and that's boring as well).

Comment: Format is the fastest way

Comment: I'd question the workflow… why do you have to delete masses of data to keep a backup up to date?

Comment: Moab7: yes, but after formatting I have to switch BitLocker on and Print and save new recovery key. And that is time consuming as well.

Comment: Tetsujin: it is simple copy of my PC files. For me it is the most reliable way of backup.

Comment: Why do you have to securely wipe a HDD that is already encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem could be using Windows File Explorer to perform the delete operation. It does more than what you ask of it. Like calculating the number of files or how long it will take - that takes longer than performing the delete operation.

You could try from the command prompt which will be faster. Use `rmdir` to quickly delete a folder. i.e. `rmdir /s /q <directory to delete>`.

However, I think you might be asking the wrong question. The problem here is your method of backup. It’s inefficient. If you want a reliable, consistent backup using a similar methodology then use `robocopy` with the `/mir` switch. i.e. `robocopy /mir <source> <destination>` this creates a perfect mirror of the source at the destination. No need to delete or keep track of changed files. You can run this command over and over and `robocopy` will only copy what has changed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 0):

I agree, possibly your backup method should be given a thought.
As for deletion speed: best would be an ssd, deleting files will be much faster, maybe 5-10 times.